# Creating a conditional SQL select statement that inserts based on a count in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, insert, case

I am trying to develop a statement that counts the sizes of a product and insert a statement base on the amount of that count.

For Example,

I have a shirt that has 3 sizes (S, M, L) For reach size I would need to insert a SQL statement.
The insert statement is to insert on Table 2 the menu position.

Table1

```
ID |  Product | Size
1      Shirt      S  
2      Shirt      M
3      Shirt      L
```

Table2

```
ID  |  Dropdown_menu_Position
1        0
2        1
3        2
```

I know the following query is incorrect but I am struggling with the logic behind it. Any SQL guru can help solve or guide me in the right direction?

```
INSERT INTO Table2
CASE
WHEN COUNT (SIZE) = 1 THEN
     SELECT NULL, '0' 
WHEN COUNT (SIZE) = 2 THEN
     SELECT NULL, '1' 
WHEN COUNT (SIZE) = 3 THEN
     SELECT NULL, '2' 
ELSE ''
END
```

I am new at making CASE statement and maybe an IF statement would work better for this, but neither one I know.

Comment: First your query says count(size) = 1?  But that is an ID not the size in your table structure.  Looks like what you need is just a simple insert into table (column list) select columnes from table

Comment: Can you give a more exact picture of what you're inserting where... I'm with @Brad5   I don't think a Case statement is what you're after at all... Maybe an INSERT INTO `YourSchema`.`YourTableName2` (`Col1`, `Col2`, `Col3`) 
SELECT 
FROM `YourTableName1`....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you are using MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions for this. They can be used to generate a numbering based on a group:

```
insert into Table2(Id, Dropdown_menu_Position)
select
  t.ID,
  --t.Product,
  --t.Size,
  ROW_NUMBER() over (
    order by s.SortOrder
  ) partition by (t.Product) as Dropdown_menu_Position
from
  Table1 t
  inner join (
    -- Inlined now, but maybe you can make a lookup table for this
    select 'XS' as Size, 0 as SortOrder
    union all select 'S', 1
    union all select 'M', 2
    union all select 'L', 3
    union all select 'XL', 4
    union all select 'XXL', 5
  ) s on s.Size = t.Size
```

In earlier versions of MySQL, these functions don't exist, and this won't work. However, for this particular case, you should indeed be able to use `count` to check how many rows there are before the current one. If you have a separate table for the sizes, this query is quite readable, but if not, you would have to embed the lookup table twice in the query. The sample below assumed a separate table:

```
-- Assuming a lookup table like this:
create table Sizes as
  select 'XS' as Size, 0 as SortOrder
  union all select 'S', 1
  union all select 'M', 2
  union all select 'L', 3
  union all select 'XL', 4
  union all select 'XXL', 5;

-- Select all IDs and how often a smaller size exists for that product
insert into Table2(Id, Dropdown_menu_Position)
select
  t.ID,
  ( select count(*)
    from 
      Table1 t2
      inner join Sizes s2 on s2.Size = t2.Size 
    where
      t2.Product = t.Product and
      s2.SortOrder < s.SortOrder) as Dropdown_menu_Position
from
  Table1 t
  inner join Sizes s on s on s.Size = t.Size
```

But, maybe you don't need the numbers in Table2 to be consecutive. Maybe it's okay, as long as they have the right order (so M is below S in the menu). This will, of course, depend on your code, but if that is possible, you can simply write this:

```
insert into Table2(Id, Dropdown_menu_Position)
select
  t.ID,
  s.SortOrder
from
  Table1 t
  inner join (
    -- Inlined now, but maybe you can make a lookup table for this
    select 'XS' as Size, 0 as SortOrder
    union all select 'S', 1
    union all select 'M', 2
    union all select 'L', 3
    union all select 'XL', 4
    union all select 'XXL', 5
  ) s on s.Size = t.Size
```

Comment: another alternative according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1895127/10285235) would be:
`select
   t1.ID as ID
  ,@rowid:=@rowid+1 as Dropdown_menu_Position
from Table1 t1, (SELECT @rowid:=-1) x
where t1.Product = 'Shirt'`

Comment: Yup, thanks for bringing that up. That's the "old" way around not having window functions. I would use that if strictly needed, but it doesn't have my preference in terms of readability. But maybe that's because I mostly work on different databases than MySQL. :-)